# Count each elements for each date in a column

Tags: r, count

I have the following data set

```
Start_time    Distance
1/1/2016         6
1/1/2016         7
```

When i apply this code:

```
test2 <- test1 %>% group_by(Start_time = lubridate::date(Start_time)) %>% summarise(Distance = sum(Distance))
```

I get the following results

```
Start_time     Distance
1/1/2016          13
```

But this is now what im looking for exactly, i would like to count distances according to this date, so would like to receive the following

```
Start_time      Distance
1/1/2016           2
```

Comment: Use `summarise(Distance = n())` or if you want unique distances, `summarise(Distance = n_distinct(Distance))`

Comment: @akrun Appreciate it , working perfectly

Comment: @akrun, Absolutely, need 10 minutes at least to accept the answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `summarise`, we can use `n()` to get the number of elements in each group or if we want number of unique elements in 'Distance', `n_distinct(Distance)` can be used

```
library(dplyr)
test1 %>%
   group_by(Start_time = lubridate::date(Start_time)) %>%
   summarise(Distance = n())
```